# Hokuyo_node with groovy

Tags: ros-groovy, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use an Hokuyo laser with groovy.
I followed the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Tutorial/UsingTheHokuyoNode but I have a problem when I want to see the laser scan in Rviz.
The config file /hokuyo_test.vcg was created for fuerte and is not used anymore with groovy. So when I launch Rviz nothing happens.

Any advice ?

Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55892/hokuyo_node-with-groovy/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just add a Laser Scan display to rviz and select the laser topic.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-02-21**:
Thanks for the advice, but the problem is that no topic is available for the laser scan.
Moreover, the frame /laser is not available in Fixed Frame...

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-21**:
That is because no one publishes that. If you just want to look at the laser data, it's OK to manually enter the frame in the fixed frame field.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-02-21**:
The problem is solved. For my part, I had to use the topic /scan and not /laser but I entered it in the fixed frame field as you said and it works. Thanks.

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-03-25**:
Hi I am having the same issue, however when I add "/scan" to the fixed frame, under global options, I am still getting a Global Status warning  "No tf data, Actual error: Fixed frame [/scan/] does not exist"

I know scan is being published as I can stream it over the command line with rostopic

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-03-25**:
Hi Henry, did you try to manually put /laser in the fixed frame and to use /scan in the topic of the Laser Scan ?

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-03-26**:
aaaaah woops...had /scan in both, putting /laser in the fixed frame now displays the data. Thank you!

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-08**:
hi guys
i try to use hokuyo laser but when i write "rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node"
this error occurd" [rospack] Error: stack/package hokuyo_node not found"
what can i do?

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-09-08**:
Hi ! Did you install hokuyo_node package ?

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-08**:
hi Caroline
I'm beginner in ros
how can i install hokuyo_node pkg?

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-09-08**:
If you are using Ubuntu, just do sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-laser-drivers (stack containing hokuyo_node package http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node).

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-08**:
i write "sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-laser-drivers" this error occurd  "Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-laser-drivers"
so i use this command"sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-urg-node"
but when i type "rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node" this error occurd" [rospack] Error: stack/package hokuyo_node not found"